# Ремонт авторизации на сайте в определенных браузерах

Tags: php

Доброго всем времени суток.

Есть сайт, во все страницы сайта добавлен путем include файлик unlock.php, который разрешает входить только по логину и паролю. В нем самом на первой строчке подключаются переменные - так что на нее не обращайте внимания. Содержимое unlock.php:

```
<?php
  include("tut_peremennye.php");
  if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
      header("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Admin Page\"");
      header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
      exit();
  } else {
      if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
          $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] = mysql_escape_string($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']);
          $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] = mysql_escape_string($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']);
      }
      $query = "SELECT a23,code_a FROM admin WHERE a22='" . $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] . "'";
      $lst = @mysql_query($query);
      $a23_passw = mysql_result($lst, 0, 'a23');
      $admin = mysql_result($lst, 0, 'code_a');
      if (!$lst) {
          header("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Admin Page\"");
          header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
          exit();
      }
      if (mysql_num_rows($lst) == 0) {
          header("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Admin Page\"");
          header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
          exit();
      }
      $a23 = @mysql_fetch_array($lst);
      if ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] != $a23_passw) {
          header("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Admin Page\"");
          header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
          exit();
      }
  }
?>
```

Опера и эксплорер работают с этим замечательно, но вот мозилла и хром выдают одну и ту же ошибку, причем не сразу, а когда я ввожу логин и пасс и нажимаю "ок":

> `Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 6 in \unlock.php on line 4
> Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 6 in \unlock.php on line 4
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at \unlock.php:4) in \unlock.php on line 6
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at \unlock.php:4) in \unlock.php on line 6`

Подскажите, что не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка тут **mysql_result( $lst, 0, 'a23' );**

Если пользователя нет в базе, то и строки не будет, вот и выскакивает ошибка. Т.е. Причина ошибки в том, что ваш запрос к базе ничего не возвращает.
Чтоб ошибка не выскакивала поставьте **@**. Но проблему это не решит, кроме как уберет показ самой ошибки. Скорее всего запрос составлен некорректно. А лучше используйте `mysql_fetch_assoc()` или `mysql_fetch_array()`

Comment: эмм... я как бы написал. что в IE и Опере все нормально. т.е. с тем же логином и паролем - все должно работать. @ поставить где или вместо чего? с mysql_fetch_assoc() или mysql_fetch_array() вообще не работает.

Comment: `@mysql_result( $lst, 0, 'a23' );` а `mysql_fetch_assoc` и `mysql_fetch_array` надо тоже уметь использовать, а не просто поменять функцию.

А работоспособность PHP кода от браузера не зависит, т.к. его выполнение происходит на сервере, а не в браузере клиента. Максимум что может быть - различие в кодировке передаваемых данных.

Допустим, данные в базе лежат в utf-8, опера и ишак передают тоже в utf, а лиса может в какой-то другой. Скорее всего так оно и есть. Попробуйте завести пользователя с логином и паролем "1" и проверьте ваш код во всех браузерах.

Comment: То же самое :(

Comment: перед `mysql_result` сделайте `echo mysql_num_rows()` и посмотрите сколько результатов запроса возвращается под разными браузерами. Там где не работает - будет НОЛЬ. А это значит, что запрос ничего не возвращает. Тогда сделайте еще `echo $query` и посмотрите как выглядит ваш запрос под разными браузерами. Наверняка там где не работает на месте `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` будет какая-то ерунда.

Comment: сделал. какая-то ерунда == какой то ерунде. вопрос не в том, как это увидеть, а как это обойти... или переписать, на что то еще.

Comment: у вас не *ерунда* должна ровняться *ерунде*, а *a22=* должно быть равно *ерунде* //извиняюсь за каламбур.
Вы бы скопипастили все-таки запрос сюда, чтоб посмотреть что за "ерунда".
А вообще, лучше воспользуйтесь каким-нибудь "прямым" скриптом авторизации, а не через http. Ну в крайнем случае через .htaccess закрыть под пароль папку админки.

Comment: Все сделал, FF все равно не может сделать элементарный запрос, т.к. оказывается mysql_num_rows() все же равно ноль. Через .htaccess делать не охота. Думаю, что уход к другому типу авторизации, это уже для другой темы вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Выпишите серверные переменные, чтобы посмотреть, что передается под каким браузером для начала. `print_r($_SERVER);` - ибо у вас выборка из базы идет по переменной `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']`.

Comment: куда вписать то? может как то часть авторизации написать по другому?

Comment: Просто в начало этого скрипта поставить перед строкой

    $query = "SELECT a23,code_a FROM admin WHERE a22='" . $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] . "'";